# Highlighting rows of a GridView on hover - How to pass GridView as a paramter into separate JavaScript file?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am learning jQuery and I am doing practise.
**My task is: Highlighting GridView row on hover**
I have written the following code in .aspx page

```
<script src="Scripts/HighlightGridViewRow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr").hover(
function() {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
},
function() {
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
});
    });
</script>
```

**Nothing jQuery specific code in code behind.**

How can I move my javascript code written in .aspx page into one separate .js file?

Thanks in Advance,

Ashok kumar.

Comment: you can move all your script in separate JS. What's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the JQuery hover on a function and place it on a JS file.

Make a call to that function by passing the clientID as parameter.

Do something like this.

Calling function is on `.aspx` page:-

```
highLight(<%=GridView1.ClientID%>);
```

Function is on **JS** file:-

```
function highLight(cid)
{   
    $("#"+cid+" tr").hover(
        function() {     
            $(this).addClass("highlight"); 
        }, 
        function() {     
            $(this).removeClass("highlight"); 
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply Siva charan.

Where can I call highLight(<%=GridView1.ClientID%>);  in .aspx?
Infact, I don't want to write even single line of code in .aspx file. Can you please suggest me how to do the same in code behind? In which event method to right the code?